# RabbitMq SSL setup TLS server: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:1368 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Bad Certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

Setting up Rabbitmq with SSL
TLS server: In-state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:1368 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Bad Certificate

ERROR c.t.a.derived.broker.RabbitMQBroker - Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

What can cause these error?
What is the role of the common name while generating a certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the client doesn't trust the CA. Make sure the client has the CA available.

Comment: can you please provide a sample command to do so, just wanted to check I might be missing. Thanks!